# How to detect the w3.org's bot in PHP?

Tags: php, w3c, w3c-validation, bots

I would like to detect w3c validator's bot in PHP. So if somebody try to validate my site on http://validator.w3.org , I would like to do something else in Php.

Comment: This seems like one of the dumbest things anyone could ever do. If you don't care about validation, that's cool. If you do care, that's also cool. Validation of code is useless nowadays anyway - ensuring the structure is such that all rendering engines parse it correctly is useful, validating is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function w3c(){
if((stristr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],'w3c') === TRUE))
return true;
}

if(w3c()){
    // this is the w3c
}
```

And if you want to hide something from the w3c validator just use:

```
if(!w3c()){
    // this is not visible for the w3c validator
}
```

Comment: As of July 2014, the full user agent string I got was "W3C_Validator/1.3 http://validator.w3.org/services".